# Can Canonical give me official support for promoting an Ubuntu install fest?

Tags: system-installation, canonical, community

I would like to promote a Ubuntu Install Fest. Can Canonical give me official support for it?

I would like to do a Install Fest with posters, mugs, etc. The problem is I don't have money.

Can someone, or Canonical help me?

My place:  Rio de Janeiro - RJ , Brazil

Comment: probably their marketing can help you. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MarketingTeam

Comment: Close voters: How is this too broad? Canonical employees answer questions here all the time, and this might not even require an employee answer. I'm sure there is info about this already on the net somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is [Ubuntu donations funding](http://community.ubuntu.com/help-information/funding/). The person who applies needs to be an Ubuntu member.

> How to apply for funding Applying for funding is simple. Please first
> review the guidelines above and then simply go to this form and fill
> in the form and we will follow up with you soon.
>
> Examples   Here are some examples of common areas we will likely fund:
>
> - Sponsorship for upstream events and LoCo Team events.
> - LoCo costs (e.g. postage costs for sending equipment to different team members).
> - Equipment (e.g. if a community member wants to add support for the equipment to Ubuntu).
> - Travel (e.g. coverage of full or part of the expenses for attending an event).
>
> Here are some things we will not fund:
>
> - Anything illegal.
> - Sending a check for an amount to an individual or
>   team.
>
> Q: What can I ask for funding for?
> A: You can ask for funding for
> items that needs purchasing that bring value to the Ubuntu community
> (e.g. sponsorship of an event, equipment, travel etc). Please note
> that we will only approve requests where the money will benefit the
> Ubuntu family of projects (Ubuntu and flavors).

Comment: "Anything illegal."
A:right, my focus is on it...

"Travel (e.g. coverage of full or part of the expenses for attending an event)."
A: well , i cannot travel, so i want to do in my neighborhood. "no expenses", i don't have money to travel or help people for it...

Comment: @Erikcht: The bullet points above are examples. If you or someone else who is involved applies, you'll need to explain how the activities will benefit the Ubuntu community. (No point in elaborating on it here.)

Comment: I would like to do a install fest in the same mod of FLISOL , 
Using Free software , like thunderbird, firefox, Libreoffice and others.

I would like , if we have gamers on the place, installing games free-for-all  to people play